# Is there an API in QML similar to setMask() API of QT?

Tags: qt, qml

We want to make a particular region of a QML rectangle transparent.

In case of QT, to do the same thing, we have used the setMask API of QWidget.

Is there any API in QML which does the same.

What I feel is that we can use the pass the QML rectangle to the QT cpp file and use setMask() API on the rectangle, but will this be possible?

Thanks,
Abhijeet Shah

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything to do this simply. Unless we're talking about rectangles only.

Anyway, you might want to try MaskedImage from QML Arsenal: https://github.com/omailson/qml-maskeditem or MaskedItem, which seems to be usable: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCOMPONENTS-388.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the only way to do it at time is making your own `QDeclarativeItem` and using the C++ functions to add a mask to your Item.

Support to masking in plain QML Items was [suggested](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-11258) to the QT developers and, as reported, will be released in QtQuick 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try gradient:

```
Gradient{
  id: id
  GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "transparent" }
  GradientStop { position: 0.9; color: "transparent" }
  GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "red"}
}
```